# WooCommerce Auto-Delete Failed Orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, status, orders

One of the Payment Gateways I use changes the Order status from "Processing" to "Failed" whenever the transaction fails or user cancels the transaction. When the customer later tries to pay for a failed order the payment gateway throws an error "Duplicate Order ID." So to avoid this issue I want to auto-delete failed orders as and when they occur.

There is a [similar question on this site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/246987/automatically-remove-a-canceled-order-in-woocommerce/246991) but the solution given there doesn't seem to work.

The code mentioned there look like this.

```
 <?php
function update_order_status( $order_id ) {
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$order_status = $order->get_status();

if ('cancelled' == $order_status || 'failed' == $order_status ||   'pending' == $order_status ) {    
        wp_delete_post($order_id,true);    
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this custom function hooked in `woocommerce_order_status_changed` action hook, that is triggered when order status change.

You will need to **set in the function the related payment gateway** (the Gateway ID)…

This function will detect order status changes (for this defined payment gateway) when status change to "cancelled" and from "processing" to "failed" statuses.

So for this particular payment gateway and this particular order status changes, all data related to the current order will be completely erased from database.

*In Woocommerce all orders submitted to payment gateways start with a "pending" status, so we will not use it.*

The code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'auto_destroy_failed_orders', 10, 4 );
function auto_destroy_failed_orders( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ){
    // HERE set your payment Gateway ID (look in WC settings > checkout to get the Gateway ID)
    $gateway_id = 'paypal';

    if ( $order->get_payment_method() != $gateway_id ) return; // Only for this payment gateway

    if ( ( $old_status == 'processing' && $new_status == 'failed' ) || $new_status == 'cancelled' ) {
        wp_delete_post( $order_id, true );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested and works.

> **Inconvenient:** When order get destroyed on order status change in edit-order backend, you will be redirected to posts list page, instead to be redirected to the order edit page as it doesn't exist anymore… I have tried to make a delay using `wp_schedule_single_event()`, but I cant get it working with it…

Comment: Hello LoicTheAztec, thanks for the time and effort. I have tested it on localserver but the code doesn't seem to work in my case ( I did replace 'paypal' with 'paytm in above code.' ). The Payment gateway in question is Paytm **[Plugin link](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Woocommerce_v2.x_Kit/tree/master/Wordpress_v4.x_compatible)** with Gateway ID 'paytm'. The product type is Virtual + Downloadable. I also use Woocommerce Subscriptions along with Woocommerce plugin.

Comment: @ManjunathPmfIas The code works perfectly on my test server for any payment gateway on any orders kinds... So I don't know what to change or to say…

Comment: It didn't work on the localserver but when I tested it on the Live server it worked. Actually, it creates more problems that it solves. I simply dropped the idea. Thanks for your time.